# Updating ffmpeg on Ubuntu 12.04; conflicts with old version from standard repository

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, ubuntu-12.04, libx264

I have never used ffmpeg on my Ubuntu Linux 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) box until now. Typing 'ffmpeg' at the command prompt revealed that ffmpeg  0.8.17 (listed as ffmpeg 0.8.17-4:0.8.17-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) was installed. Seeing as I need to convert h.265 to h.264, an update was obviously required.

Following posted [instructions](https://www.mariusv.com/compile-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-karmic), I installed a ream of packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install faad libmp4v2-dev libfaac0 libfaac-dev
libxvidcore4 libxvidcore4-dev liba52-0.7.4 liba52-0.7.4-dev libx264-dev
libgsm-tools libogg-dev libtheora-bin libfaad-dev libvorbis-dev 
libtheora-dev libdts-dev git-core yasm texi2html checkinstall
```

followed by

```
$ sudo apt-get purge ffmpeg
```

in order to get rid of the old stuff from the original repo.

Downloaded the latest ffmpeg, and a .*"/configure; make; sudo make install"* later, I should be in business.

Except that typing 'ffmpeg' at the prompt still fired up the old version. A quick look revealed that the old ffmpeg binary was still sitting in /usr/bin with the new one being installed in /usr/local/bin. But ffmpeg is no longer listed as an installed package, and *sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg* tells me that "Package ffmpeg is not installed, so not removed".

Running /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg directly works, however then fails in an *Unknown encoder 'libx264'* error. Which is puzzling because the package *libx264-120* is installed and */usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libx264.so.120* (with the appropriate symlink to */usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libx264.so*) does exist.

Maybe I've been looking at this for too long, because I'm sure this is a simple issue but I just can't see it.

Can someone please hand me the stupid had and point out why I deserve to wear it?

Tnx!

Comment: If you wanted to compile you should have followed [FFmpeg Wiki: Compile on Ubuntu](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu). The outdated guide you followed made you install unused and useless packages, and installed stuff into the system directories which is unnecessary. Alternatively, you could simply [download a recent binary of `ffmpeg`](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and avoid compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find out which package provides this old binary in `/usr/bin` by running

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/ffmpeg
```

Then remove that package in turn.

Note that if that file is a symlink, esp. to `/etc/alternatives`, you should follow the trail of symlinks and then run the above command on the actual binary.

Comment: And there it is - the stupid hat. :-) The offending package was libav-tools. Removing it solved the version conflict. The x264 issue seems to have to do with the new ffmpeg build, which is a separate issue.

Tnx!